# Access dynamically created class instance variable, Kivy framework

Tags: python, kivy

Imagine following structure (I've cut most imho relevant parts):

```
class mymodificatorclass:
  def callback(self,object):
    print object

class generator(BoxLayout):
  #(...)
  def add(self, *l):
    for i,t in enumerate(self.texts):
      self.mytext.append(TextInput(hint_text=t, on_text_validate=modify.callback(self)))
      self.add_widget(self.mytext[i])

#(...)
modify = mymodificatorclass() #global scope variable
```

prints for example <**main**.generator object at 0x433eef0>. Which is fine. 
But, how would one access this class instance variables?

meaning, desired output would be:

```
print XXXXX
$ <__main__.mytext object at 0x433eef0>
print XXXXX.text, XXXXX
$ "text inside" <__main__.mytext object at 0x433eef0>
```

I've checked:

```
print object.__class__.__dict__.items() #no mytext here
print object.mytext #no mytext here
print getattr(object,object.mytext) # object generator has no attribute mytext
```

I know i can assign for example additional variable storing each TextInput object, but i'd rather not, since i know that if I modified example like this:

```
class generator(BoxLayout):
  def add(self, *l):
    for i,t in enumerate(self.texts):
      self.mytext.append(TextInput(hint_text=t, on_text_validate=self.callback))
      self.add_widget(self.mytext[i])

  def callback(self,object):
    print object
```

i would get desired result (i had that like this, but decided i need to move closer to mvc )

Comment: self.mytext.append(TextInput(hint_text=t, on_text_validate=modify.callback(self))) you are calling the function instead of passing it. use functools.partial.
self.mytext.append(TextInput(hint_text=t, on_text_validate=partial(modify.callback, self)))

Comment: Thats it. Please post an answer, for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.mytext.append(TextInput(hint_text=t,
                             on_text_validate=modify.callback(self)))
```

You are calling the function instead of passing it. Use [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
self.mytext.append(TextInput(hint_text=t,
                             on_text_validate=partial(modify.callback, self)))
```